# How to tell if OpenGL is really working in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, graphics-card, opengl

I have a lenovo S9e running Intel integrated graphics.  Here is my lspci output related to the graphics:

```
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3870
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Memory at f0580000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
```

I want to know how I can make sure OpenGL support is running in full on an Ubuntu 10.04 installation. I have a few hints to think that it is not:

- The "Desktop Effects" will not load
- Apps such as stardock, when
  attempting to use OpenGL rendering,
  will display black boxes instead of
  transparency
- In the games Pioneers, the number-tile icons are suspiciously just black circles
- Windows games running with Wine will only support software rendering, not hardware rendering
- When I boot into a Knoppix LiveCD, the desktop effects do work, splendidly, meaning compiz detects my computer as capable.

My problem with troubleshooting is that Canonical has basically eliminated the conf-file-based mechanism of X11 as far as I can tell, thus making it even harder to ensure graphics modules are loading properly.

How do I debug and test OpenGL on m Ubuntu 10.04 installation?

Comment: Does `glxgears` run properly? You can create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` anyway and Ubuntu will use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run

```
glxinfo | grep '^direct rendering:'
```

and if it shows `Yes` then you have 3D acceleration, and hence OpenGL.

Comment: it says yes. Any suggestions as to why then various effects won't run under 10.04 but will under Knoppix?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [disabling KMS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes#Working%20around%20bugs%20in%20the%20new%20kernel%20video%20architecture).

(That's not really an answer to your question, sorry, but it might solve your issues. ;) )

Comment: This is a huge help! I disabled KMS and at the very least, upon testing, I can now use visual effects in 10.04! I am now off to test some Wine games.  Cheers!